# Displaying video file in an imported SWF file fullscreen in Flash Actionscript 3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, video, fullscreen

I am using a flipbook Flash/Actionscript 3.0 framework for a digital magazine
http://www.digital-brochure.com/

You can have videos embedded in the pages of the flipbook, but they can not be displaye fullscreen like Youtube videos, for example.

The flipbook can also import swf files to display as pages of the flipbook, so another way of embedding videos into a page of the flipbook would be to have the video player in the swf page you are embedding. This gives you more control over the style and the positioning of the video.

My question is: Is there a way with AS3.0 to togle the embedded video from normal predefined size to fullscreen and back? This has to work even when the swf page is embedded into the parent swf flipbook pagepage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this will work or not, based on the fact that you're nesting swf's into each other, but try this:

```
function goFullScreen(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.NORMAL) {
        stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
    } else {
        stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
    }
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goFullScreen)
```

If you want, you could also set that listener to a button, or to keystroke ofcourse. One thing to keep in mind also, is adapting your html to allow fullscreen. Which is done by adding a param  in your embed/object tags.

Also, remember, this will only work in a browser. It will not work when you test four movie in the flash IDE.